# What is the difference between object.operator bool() and (bool) object?

Tags: c++, c++11, gdb, clang++, conversion-operator

I have a class for which I have overloaded the operator bool explicitly like this :-

```
class Foo {
  explicit operator bool() {
    // return_something_here
  }
};
```

However, when I run the following two in gdb I get :-

```
gdb) p fooobj.operator bool()
$7 = true
gdb) p (bool)(fooobj)
$8 = false
```

What's the difference between the two invocations and why do they return different things?

Edit :- I'm using the clang compiler.

Note :- The second value (false) is the correct value that I want to be returned using the first syntax. I'm using a codegen so I don't have complete control over what c++ gets generated in case anyone is curious why I don't just use the second syntax.

Even in that case, the difference between the two would still be an unanswered question.

Comment: FWIW, there is no difference between `fooobj.operator bool()` and `(bool)(fooobj)` in C++. I don't know how they are different in gdb.

Comment: @RSahu That is exactly what my understanding was. However, it definitely doesn't seem to be working that way.

Comment: There is [no difference](https://ideone.com/V88alD). Your question seems to be more about the operation of GDB than about C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB Hmm, It may be the case that this is a quirk of gdb.

Comment: @owagh: Something tells me that gdb probably isn't a complete C++ REPL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran a few quick tests, and it appears to be that gdb doesn't handle code compiled with clang well.  Here is a test program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
  Foo() : m_Int(0) {}
  operator bool() {
    return true;  // also tried false here
  }
private:
  int m_Int;
};

int main()
{
  Foo f;
  if (f.operator bool()) cout << "operator bool is true.\n";

  if ((bool)f)  cout << "(bool)f is true.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

When the binary is run, the output is as expected, i.e. (bool)f is the same as f.operator bool(), regardless of the compiler.  However, if gdb is used with code build using g++, then the `p` command behaves correctly.  Yet when gdb is run on code built using clang++, I get:

```
(gdb) print f.operator bool()
Couldn't find method Foo::operatorbool
(gdb)
```

I'm running clang v. 3.4, gcc v. 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

In fact, a quick search revealed this: [Is it possible to debug a gcc-compiled program using lldb, or debug a clang-compiled program using gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132194/is-it-possible-to-debug-a-gcc-compiled-program-using-lldb-or-debug-a-clang-comp).  So, I tried `lldb`, and it worked as expected.  This is consistent with the comment that was added as I was investigating.

Comment: for completeness, you could try installing `lldb` also and see how it fares?

Comment: Good well-written answer. Accepted!